# How to read email from command line in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, email, unix, command-line

I have a server with roundcube installed in it. I tried sending email into it from external email with my username@servername. It turns out that I was not able to read emails (no email pops up in inbox) but when I send email to some external email address from roundcube then it works fine. I was wondering if there is any command-line code to read any emails that any user @server receives.

Comment: You have to install a command line mail reader. Please ask on superuser or another site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. There is a nearly 30 yrs old 'mail' command. But an

```
apt-get install alpine
```

helped a lot as well.